# Accessing an external project with add-subdirectory results in CMake Error related to export set

Tags: c++, cmake, spdlog

I have a project A that depends on spdlog. Here is the structure:

```
|--- dir A
...|---src
......|---CMakeLists.txt
...|---include
...|---CMakeLists.txt
|---external/3rd_party/spdlog
```

I am trying to access spdlog in project A by adding a subdirectory. Here is how my `A/CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project(GLOBAL CXX)
add_subdirectory(../external/3rd_party/spdlog   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Here is how my `A/src/CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Alib CXX)

if(NOT TARGET spdlog)
   # Stand-alone build
   find_package(spdlog_header_only REQUIRED)
endif()
add_librray(A A.cpp)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC spdlog_header_only)

install(TARGETS A
   EXPORT ATargets
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)
install(EXPORT ATargets
    NAMESPACE A::
    FILE ATargets.cmake
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR})

install(FILES AConfig.cmake DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR})
```

When I try to build this, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "ATargets" ...) includes target "A" which requires target "spdlog_header_only" that is not in the export set.
```

Please can you suggest me how to fix it?

For some reason I need to maintain the same directory structure I have shown above.
Here is a related question but does not have an answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777734/install-export-requires-target-from-subproject)

Comment: Is ${PATH} actually resolving to something? Isn't that an environment variable in CMake? A .. should have worked.

Comment: @user3389943 by ${PATH} I meant some random path to the external directory. I have made the changes. Please let me  know if it makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Meaining of the error

Since you use `PUBLIC` keyword when link your library (`A`) with `spdlog_header_only`, CMake expects that this linking is also needed for **users** of your library. So, when you create config file for your library (with `install(EXPORT)`), CMake adds linking with `spdlog_header_only` target into the config file too. Like

```
# [ATargets.cmake]
target_link_libraries(A::A PUBLIC spdlog_header_only)
```

Linking with a target implies existence of this target, but you do **not install** `spdlog_header_only` target. Because of that, created config file for your library won't work. This is what CMake tells you in the error message.

#### Simple fix

The simplest fix would be using `PRIVATE` linking with `spdlog_header_only` target, so that linking won't be part of the config file. Beware, in that case a user of your (installed) library won't get access to the header files for `spdlog`.
(But a user could obtain these headers by other means.)

#### Hard fix

But if you want a user of your library to have access to `spdlog` headers (or, worse, the **public** headers of your library use `#include` for headers from `spdlog`), then you cannot drop `PUBLIC` linking. In that case you need to **install** `spdlog_header_only` target too. E.g. by enabling `SPDLOG_INSTALL` option

```
set(SPDLOG_INSTALL ON)
```

before

```
add_subdirectory(../external/3rd_party/spdlog   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/spdlog  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

(Note, that aside from enabling `SPDLOG_INSTALL` option, several other adjustments needs to be done for make the config file for your library to work.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The solution worked :)
That was really insightful :) 
@Tsyvarev